# How to specify the years on an axis when using plot() on DateTime objects

Tags: python, matplotlib

The plotting goes like this:

`plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])`

`df['Date']` consists of DateTime objects with several years and `df['Price']` are integers.
However on the actual line graph, it automatically selects about 4 years spaced apart in the graph with large intervals:

[image]

How do I make it so that I can specify the number of years to show on the X axis? Or perhaps show all the years (year only)?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random

dates = []
prices = []

for count in range(10000):
    prices.append(random.randint(0, 10))
    dates.append(datetime.datetime(random.randint(1960, 2022), random.randint(1, 12), random.randint(1, 27)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

data = {
    'Date': dates,
    'Price': prices
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ignore_index = True)

df_temp = df.copy()
df_temp['Date DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp['Date'])
df_temp = df_temp.drop(axis = 'columns', columns = 'Date')
df = df_temp
df
```

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5), dpi = 1000)
plt.plot(df['Date DT'], df['Price'])

# Labels
plt.xlabel('Dates', fontsize = 8) 
plt.ylabel('Prices', fontsize = 8) 

# Save
plt.title('Example', fontsize = 15)
plt.savefig('example.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Comment: Why is it that you didn't include reproducible test data and code? Nor an image of the plot? Did you try to plot via pandas instead of directly via matplotlib (e.g. something like `df.set_index('Data').plot(y='Price')`)?

Comment: @JohanC I have included example code now, though I cannot share the dataset. I hope DateTime and Integers are easy enough to randomize and create a dataframe.

Comment: Please, never add confidential data. Whenever possible, try to use minimal test data that reproduces the problem.  Without your code, it is unclear what exactly you mean by "DateTime", as there exist many many ways such data can be stored.  As the y-axis isn't important, you can just use some constant value. But, please try to understand that reproducible test data are super important to be able to tackle your question. Did you try to plot via pandas?  Could you add an image (as the data is confidential, you could just show the x-axis)?

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for bearing with me, I've made up some code to randomize values to get the same result, only that the line graph is all over the place but that is not the concern here. I also added an image as you suggested: there you can see 7 labels but the years range from `1960-2022`, so that's 62 labels. So what I want is to maybe get it to 30 labels, or possibly all 62.

Comment: Did you try https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.YearLocator ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xticks function to set the tick marks and labels on the x-axis.

Like This:

```
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])

years = [date.year for date in df['Date']]

plt.xticks(df['Date'], years, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

**EDIT:** to only display one unique year each out of years:

```
import numpy as np

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])

# Extract the unique years from the 'Date' column
years = np.unique([date.year for date in df['Date']])

# Set the tick marks on the x-axis
plt.xticks(df['Date'], rotation=45)

# Set the labels of the tick marks on the x-axis
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(years)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Problem with this is that there are way too many X Axis labels now as there are many entries in the Dataframe with duplicate year values. How do I get this to only display one unique year each out of `years`?

Comment: you will need to extract the unique years from the df['Date'] column using the unique function from NumPy, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Yes I have tried this solution but since the number of entries `df['Date']` greatly differs from `years`, a `ValueError` occurs: The number of FixedLocator locations (xxxx), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (x).